# Import .xlsx with rio

Tags: r, import, row, r-rio

Good evening,

I have a problem concerning my import with the package rio.
I have given an excel-sheet (1 column, 1000 rows) with the numerics starting in the first row!
And that is basically my problem. I know how an import with rio works and that rio interpretants the first row always as a character (thinking of it as the heading). But in my given data, the first row doesn’t have any heading, it starts right away with the numerics.
So my question is basically:
How do I need to change my command so that rio reads the first row as a numeric and not as a heading/character?
My command so far:

```
library(rio)
setwd(…)
A12<-import("A12_daten.xlsx")
```

Important:
It is an exercise I have to do for college. And it is given that I have to solve the problem with the package rio!

Thank for your help & time
stay healthy

Answer (score 1):

`rio` package uses `readxl::read_excel` to [read Excel files](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rio/vignettes/rio.html).

Hence, you can use `col_names` argument from `read_excel`.

```
A12 <- import("A12_daten.xlsx", col_names = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the same issue but I solved it today. The easiest way is to add an empty row before the first row.

If you have multiple sheets to read:
The import function read the first row as a column name, so you can just convert the name into numeric and then rbind to the rest.

```
A12 <- import('A12_daten.xlsx')
rbind(as.numeric(names(A12)), A12)
```